# Ajax POST request to new Google Analytics V4 API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, google-analytics-api

Google Analytics v4 API was just released and GET requests were changed to POST requests. And there are no good examples out there yet...

So I've successfully received **accessToken**, but when I try the following POST request - I'm always getting empty object **Object { }**, but I'm sure that data is there and ViewID is correct!

Any advice helps! Thank you!

```
requestAnalyticsData1 = function (accessToken) {
    var url = "https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?";
        url += "access_token="+accessToken;

    var params = {
        "reportRequests":[{
            "viewId":"121238102",
            "dateRanges":[{
                "startDate":"yesterday",
                "endDate":"today"
            }],
            "metrics":[{
              "expression":"ga:users"
            }],
            "dimensions": [{
              "name":"ga:pagePath"
            }]
        }]
    }

    $.ajax({       
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: params,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results)
            parseAnalyticsReportsData(results);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('failed');
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to replace this part:

```
data: params,
dataType: "json",
```

With this:

```
data: JSON.stringify(params),
dataType: "json",
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
},
```